# How to (temporarily) override the ssh executable that TRAMP uses?

Tags: tramp, ssh

For reasons that I don't want to get into, for *some* `ssh` connections I need to use an executable different from the one that TRAMP uses by default.

Therefore, I am looking for a convenient way to *temporarily* override the setting of the `ssh` executable that TRAMP uses.

Comment: `C-h v tramp-methods`. You'll need to modify the `tramp-login` setting for whatever method you are interested in (and may also `tramp-login-args`). Alternatively, you might want to add your own method with the appropriate settings. Or even betterr wait for @Michael Albinus to chime in with the correct solution :-)

Comment: That's the proper solution :-)